# Installation path for .Net based components building using Any CPU

Tags: msbuild, wix, cpu-architecture

.Net Assemblies built with AnyCPU will JIT to 64-bit code when loaded into a 64-bit or 32-bit process based on the CPU. I am creating a WiX installer.
What should be the default path (Program File x86/Program File) for the components built with AnyCPU option? Shall the installer check the platform and set the appropriate path or are there any other ways to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time, I'd recommend installing to `ProgramFilesFolder` (Program files (x86)) as that is present on both 32-bit and 64-bit computers. 32-bit is the closest thing (at this time) Windows has for "Any CPU".

Note: This does change as WOW is removed from 64-bit Windows. You can already remove the WOW subsystem from Windows Server, in which case you need to provide a package that targets the appropriate architecture. It isn't clear if/when WOW will be removed from Windows client.